# ReasonML, side effecting call on x if option is Some(x)

Tags: option-type, reason, bucklescript

I have `let intervalId = option(Js.Global.intervalId)`

I would like a succinct way to do the side effecting call to `Js.Global.clearInterval` if the option has a value (ie. is `Some(id)` and not `None`)

Maybe the `Belt.Option.map` function is the answer, but I'm having problems putting it to use.

I'm very new to OCaml and ReasonML, but several languages I know have suitable functions. I'm paraphrasing some of them here to give the idea what I'm looking for:

In Scala I would say: `intervalId.foreach(Js.Global.clearInterval)`

In Swift I would say: `intervalId.map(Js.Global.clearInterval)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Belt.Option.map(intervalId, Js.Global.clearInterval)` should work fine, except it returns a value that you need to discard in some way to avoid a type error or warning.

The safest way to discard values you don't need is to assign it to the wildcard pattern and include a type annotation to ensure the value you discard is what you expect it to be:

```
let _: option(unit) = Belt.Option.map(intervalId, Js.Global.clearInterval)
```

You can also use the `ignore` function, which works particularly well at the end of a sequence of pipes, but beware that you might then accidentally partially apply a function and discard it without actually executing the function and invoking the side-effect.

```
intervalId
  |> Belt.Option.map(_, Js.Global.clearInterval)
  |> ignore
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! That works. I especially like the last "chaining" syntax.
I noticed that it even works on 1 line: `intervalId |> Belt.Option.map(_, Js.Global.clearInterval) |> ignore` (not sure if thats good style though ;) )

Comment: `|>` is really just an ordinary operator, and not whitespace-sensitive in any way. And style-wise I think it's usually fine, as long as it fits.

Answer (score 0):

For curiosity, I'll leave the obvious thing I had here before the chosen answer:

```
  switch (intervalId) {
    |Some(id) => Js_global.clearInterval(id)
    |None => ()
  }
```